# Как вставить корзину с покупками OpenCart на html сайт?

Tags: php, opencart, корзина

Есть 2 сайта на одном домене: OpenCart и статический html сайт. На сайте OpenCart есть корзина со счетчиком товаров, при клике на нее всплывают товары, которые там находятся.
Как можно вставить её на статический сайт, чтобы она брала информацию с OpenCart? Пробовал вставить код корзины, но ясно, что функционала там нету, так как там используются переменные на PHP.
Вот код корзины (файл cart.tpl):

```
<div id="cart" class="btn-group btn-block">
  <button type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" data-loading-text="<?php echo $text_loading; ?>" class="btn btn-inverse btn-block btn-lg dropdown-toggle"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> <span id="cart-total"><?php echo $text_items; ?></span></button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
    <?php if ($products || $vouchers) { ?>
    <li>
      <table class="table table-striped">
        <?php foreach ($products as $product) { ?>
        <tr>
          <td class="text-center"><?php if ($product['thumb']) { ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $product['thumb']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $product['name']; ?>" title="<?php echo $product['name']; ?>" class="img-thumbnail" /></a>
            <?php } ?></td>
          <td class="text-left"><a href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>"><?php echo $product['name']; ?></a>
            <?php if ($product['option']) { ?>
            <?php foreach ($product['option'] as $option) { ?>
            <br />
            - <small><?php echo $option['name']; ?> <?php echo $option['value']; ?></small>
            <?php } ?>
            <?php } ?>
            <?php if ($product['recurring']) { ?>
            <br />
            - <small><?php echo $text_recurring; ?> <?php echo $product['recurring']; ?></small>
            <?php } ?></td>
          <td class="text-right">x <?php echo $product['quantity']; ?></td>
          <td class="text-right"><?php echo $product['total']; ?></td>
          <td class="text-center"><button type="button" onclick="cart.remove('<?php echo $product['cart_id']; ?>');" title="<?php echo $button_remove; ?>" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button></td>
        </tr>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php foreach ($vouchers as $voucher) { ?>
        <tr>
          <td class="text-center"></td>
          <td class="text-left"><?php echo $voucher['description']; ?></td>
          <td class="text-right">x&nbsp;1</td>
          <td class="text-right"><?php echo $voucher['amount']; ?></td>
          <td class="text-center text-danger"><button type="button" onclick="voucher.remove('<?php echo $voucher['key']; ?>');" title="<?php echo $button_remove; ?>" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button></td>
        </tr>
        <?php } ?>
      </table>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>
        <table class="table table-bordered">
          <?php foreach ($totals as $total) { ?>
          <tr>
            <td class="text-right"><strong><?php echo $total['title']; ?></strong></td>
            <td class="text-right"><?php echo $total['text']; ?></td>
          </tr>
          <?php } ?>
        </table>
        <p class="text-right"><a href="<?php echo $cart; ?>"><strong><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> <?php echo $text_cart; ?></strong></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="<?php echo $checkout; ?>"><strong><i class="fa fa-share"></i> <?php echo $text_checkout; ?></strong></a></p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <?php } else { ?>
    <li>
      <p class="text-center"><?php echo $text_empty; ?></p>
    </li>
    <?php } ?>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[image: вот эта кнопка в открытом состоянии]

эта кнопка в открытом состоянии

```js
var cart = {
 'add': function(product_id, quantity) {
  $.ajax({
   url: 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/add',
   type: 'post',
   data: 'product_id=' + product_id + '&quantity=' + (typeof(quantity) != 'undefined' ? quantity : 1),
   dataType: 'json',
   beforeSend: function() {
    $('#cart > button').button('loading');
   },
   complete: function() {
    $('#cart > button').button('reset');
   },
   success: function(json) {
    $('.alert, .text-danger').remove();

    if (json['redirect']) {
     location = json['redirect'];
    }

    if (json['success']) {
     $('#content').parent().before('<div class="alert alert-success"><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> ' + json['success'] + ' <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button></div>');

     // Need to set timeout otherwise it wont update the total
     setTimeout(function () {
      $('#cart > button').html('<span id="cart-total"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> ' + json['total'] + '</span>');
     }, 100);

     $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');

     $('#cart > ul').load('index.php?route=common/cart/info ul li');
    }
   },
         error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
             alert(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
         }
  });
 },
 'update': function(key, quantity) {
  $.ajax({
   url: 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/edit',
   type: 'post',
   data: 'key=' + key + '&quantity=' + (typeof(quantity) != 'undefined' ? quantity : 1),
   dataType: 'json',
   beforeSend: function() {
    $('#cart > button').button('loading');
   },
   complete: function() {
    $('#cart > button').button('reset');
   },
   success: function(json) {
    // Need to set timeout otherwise it wont update the total
    setTimeout(function () {
     $('#cart > button').html('<span id="cart-total"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> ' + json['total'] + '</span>');
    }, 100);

    if (getURLVar('route') == 'checkout/cart' || getURLVar('route') == 'checkout/checkout') {
     location = 'index.php?route=checkout/cart';
    } else {
     $('#cart > ul').load('index.php?route=common/cart/info ul li');
    }
   },
         error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
             alert(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
         }
  });
 },
 'remove': function(key) {
  $.ajax({
   url: 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/remove',
   type: 'post',
   data: 'key=' + key,
   dataType: 'json',
   beforeSend: function() {
    $('#cart > button').button('loading');
   },
   complete: function() {
    $('#cart > button').button('reset');
   },
   success: function(json) {
    // Need to set timeout otherwise it wont update the total
    setTimeout(function () {
     $('#cart > button').html('<span id="cart-total"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> ' + json['total'] + '</span>');
    }, 100);

    if (getURLVar('route') == 'checkout/cart' || getURLVar('route') == 'checkout/checkout') {
     location = 'index.php?route=checkout/cart';
    } else {
     $('#cart > ul').load('index.php?route=common/cart/info ul li');
    }
   },
         error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
             alert(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
         }
  });
 }
}

var voucher = {
 'add': function() {

 },
 'remove': function(key) {
  $.ajax({
   url: 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/remove',
   type: 'post',
   data: 'key=' + key,
   dataType: 'json',
   beforeSend: function() {
    $('#cart > button').button('loading');
   },
   complete: function() {
    $('#cart > button').button('reset');
   },
   success: function(json) {
    // Need to set timeout otherwise it wont update the total
    setTimeout(function () {
     $('#cart > button').html('<span id="cart-total"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> ' + json['total'] + '</span>');
    }, 100);

    if (getURLVar('route') == 'checkout/cart' || getURLVar('route') == 'checkout/checkout') {
     location = 'index.php?route=checkout/cart';
    } else {
     $('#cart > ul').load('index.php?route=common/cart/info ul li');
    }
   },
         error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
             alert(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
         }
  });
 }
}

var wishlist = {
 'add': function(product_id) {
  $.ajax({
   url: 'index.php?route=account/wishlist/add',
   type: 'post',
   data: 'product_id=' + product_id,
   dataType: 'json',
   success: function(json) {
    $('.alert').remove();

    if (json['redirect']) {
     location = json['redirect'];
    }

    if (json['success']) {
     $('#content').parent().before('<div class="alert alert-success"><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> ' + json['success'] + ' <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button></div>');
    }

    $('#wishlist-total span').html(json['total']);
    $('#wishlist-total').attr('title', json['total']);

    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');
   },
         error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
             alert(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
         }
  });
 },
 'remove': function() {

 }
}

var compare = {
 'add': function(product_id) {
  $.ajax({
   url: 'index.php?route=product/compare/add',
   type: 'post',
   data: 'product_id=' + product_id,
   dataType: 'json',
   success: function(json) {
    $('.alert').remove();

    if (json['success']) {
     $('#content').parent().before('<div class="alert alert-success"><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> ' + json['success'] + ' <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button></div>');

     $('#compare-total').html(json['total']);

     $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');
    }
   },
         error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
             alert(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
         }
  });
 },
 'remove': function() {

 }
}
```

Cart add remove functions

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59830/discussion-on-question-by-nikolay------opencart--h).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вытянул данные элемента таким образом:

```html
<?php 

 $opts = array('http' => array('header'=> 'Cookie: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE']."\r\n"));
 $context = stream_context_create($opts);

 $contents = file_get_contents('http://test1.ru', false, $context);

 $first_step = explode( '<!-- cart -->' , $contents );
 $second_step = explode("<!-- cart end -->" , $first_step[1] );

 ?>
```

Потом благодаря @Alex78191 заменил в файле \catalog\view\javascript\common.js

```html
// Cart add remove functions
var baseUrl = "http://test1.ru/";
var cart = {
 'add': function(product_id, quantity) {
  $.ajax({
   url: baseUrl + 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/add',
   type: 'post',
   data: 'product_id=' + product_id + '&quantity=' + (typeof(quantity) != 'undefined' ? quantity : 1),
   dataType: 'json',
   beforeSend: function() {
    $('#cart > button').button('loading');
   },
   complete: function() {
    $('#cart > button').button('reset');
   },
   success: function(json) {
    $('.alert, .text-danger').remove();

    if (json['redirect']) {
     location = json['redirect'];
    }

    if (json['success']) {
     $('#content').parent().before('<div class="alert alert-success"><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> ' + json['success'] + ' <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button></div>');

     // Need to set timeout otherwise it wont update the total
     setTimeout(function () {
      $('#cart > button').html('<span id="cart-total"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> ' + json['total'] + '</span>');
     }, 100);

     $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');

     $('#cart > ul').load(baseUrl + 'index.php?route=common/cart/info ul li');
    }
   },
         error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
             alert(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
         }
  });
 },
 'update': function(key, quantity) {
  $.ajax({
   url: baseUrl + 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/edit',
   type: 'post',
   data: 'key=' + key + '&quantity=' + (typeof(quantity) != 'undefined' ? quantity : 1),
   dataType: 'json',
   beforeSend: function() {
    $('#cart > button').button('loading');
   },
   complete: function() {
    $('#cart > button').button('reset');
   },
   success: function(json) {
    // Need to set timeout otherwise it wont update the total
    setTimeout(function () {
     $('#cart > button').html('<span id="cart-total"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> ' + json['total'] + '</span>');
    }, 100);

    if (getURLVar('route') == 'checkout/cart' || getURLVar('route') == 'checkout/checkout') {
     location = baseUrl + 'index.php?route=checkout/cart';
    } else {
     $('#cart > ul').load(baseUrl + 'index.php?route=common/cart/info ul li');
    }
   },
         error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
             alert(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
         }
  });
 },
 'remove': function(key) {
  $.ajax({
   url: baseUrl + 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/remove',
   type: 'post',
   data: 'key=' + key,
   dataType: 'json',
   beforeSend: function() {
    $('#cart > button').button('loading');
   },
   complete: function() {
    $('#cart > button').button('reset');
   },
   success: function(json) {
    // Need to set timeout otherwise it wont update the total
    setTimeout(function () {
     $('#cart > button').html('<span id="cart-total"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> ' + json['total'] + '</span>');
    }, 100);

    if (getURLVar('route') == 'checkout/cart' || getURLVar('route') == 'checkout/checkout') {
     location = baseUrl + 'index.php?route=checkout/cart';
    } else {
     $('#cart > ul').load(baseUrl + 'index.php?route=common/cart/info ul li');
    }
   },
         error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
             alert(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
         }
  });
 }
}

var voucher = {
 'add': function() {

 },
 'remove': function(key) {
  $.ajax({
   url: baseUrl + 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/remove',
   type: 'post',
   data: 'key=' + key,
   dataType: 'json',
   beforeSend: function() {
    $('#cart > button').button('loading');
   },
   complete: function() {
    $('#cart > button').button('reset');
   },
   success: function(json) {
    // Need to set timeout otherwise it wont update the total
    setTimeout(function () {
     $('#cart > button').html('<span id="cart-total"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> ' + json['total'] + '</span>');
    }, 100);

    if (getURLVar('route') == 'checkout/cart' || getURLVar('route') == 'checkout/checkout') {
     location = baseUrl + baseUrl + 'index.php?route=checkout/cart';
    } else {
     $('#cart > ul').load(baseUrl + 'index.php?route=common/cart/info ul li');
    }
   },
         error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
             alert(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
         }
  });
 }
}

var wishlist = {
 'add': function(product_id) {
  $.ajax({
   url: baseUrl + 'index.php?route=account/wishlist/add',
   type: 'post',
   data: 'product_id=' + product_id,
   dataType: 'json',
   success: function(json) {
    $('.alert').remove();

    if (json['redirect']) {
     location = json['redirect'];
    }

    if (json['success']) {
     $('#content').parent().before('<div class="alert alert-success"><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> ' + json['success'] + ' <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button></div>');
    }

    $('#wishlist-total span').html(json['total']);
    $('#wishlist-total').attr('title', json['total']);

    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');
   },
         error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
             alert(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
         }
  });
 },
 'remove': function() {

 }
}

var compare = {
 'add': function(product_id) {
  $.ajax({
   url: baseUrl + 'index.php?route=product/compare/add',
   type: 'post',
   data: 'product_id=' + product_id,
   dataType: 'json',
   success: function(json) {
    $('.alert').remove();

    if (json['success']) {
     $('#content').parent().before('<div class="alert alert-success"><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> ' + json['success'] + ' <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button></div>');

     $('#compare-total').html(json['total']);

     $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');
    }
   },
         error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
             alert(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
         }
  });
 },
 'remove': function() {

 }
}
```

Описываю: создал переменную `var baseUrl = "http://test1.ru/";` потом везде `'index.php?route=checkout/cart/add'` заменил на `baseUrl + 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/add'`. Ну и в нужном мне месте в html сайте вывел `<?php echo $second_step[0]; ?>` А также на статическом сайте не забудьте подключить файл `<script src="../catalog/view/javascript/common.js"></script>`

Comment: PHP не нужно оформлять как Фрагмент кода на JavaScript/HTML/CSS. JS в данном случае тоже.